# Using external API calls as a data source in domain-driven-design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a two-layer application which has the bottom layer for collecting data from external APIs and adding it to database and the second layer is for return data from database that is based on the data that I collected from the external API calls.
so I managed to put the external API calls in the infrastructure repositories with their interface in the domain.
So generally where I'm exactly stuck is to save this data that I'm collecting in database without creating a model for this data in the domain since this data is dependable on the external API I want to have this two layers totally separated collecting the data and return the other data without breaking the principles of domain-driven-design.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the questions is where to put the models that are related with collecting data from this external APIs?

Comment: In an Anti-corruption layer. This may help: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/356118/236092

Comment: Or this: https://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoring-external-service.html

Comment: so generally this anti corruption layer can consist of models and services and repositories that are separated from the rest of the app but still it plays big roll on the functionality of the app? if it's possible can you provide me with an example using external API calls models and services.

Comment: that layer can be a single class or a lot of classes but what it does is to translate external models (entities and value objects) into local models.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have some examples right now.

Comment: what is the potential relationship between Domain and external API? Does the external API offer functionality used by the Domain? Is the Domain aware of the external data somehow?

Comment: @MikeSW the domain is for generating statistics, this statistics are based on the data that was collected from the external APIs,

Comment: You don't have much domain then. This is a case of straightforward CRUD. Keep things simple, not everything needs to be forced into some pattern.

Comment: @MikeSW Yes I think the same way but I'm forced to do it in that pattern since it was in the requirement so how do you think you can implement DDD in such case?

Comment: A pattern can't be a requirement. And DDD is a mindset, not a design pattern by itself. Whatever implementation you might do, it will never be a DDD specific tactical pattern  because it simply doesn't apply here. You can't force a problem into an already chosen solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [External data mapping to domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776829/external-data-mapping-to-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will try to answer here is how DDD could help and highlight that the import is an implementation detail after you applied some DDD principle to find a useful design and an appropriated implementation.

So you need data for your App/Bounded context which will have to generate statistics (if you can put more business language here DDD will be even more helpful). What is the business use of this app ? what are the languages (Ubiquitous Language) and boundaries (BC) ? How is it going to interop with others contexts (Context Mapping).

You will need implement this model, and here you could use the concepts defined and define a persistence model (potentially the language used in the API isn't the language used by your app) and also you might need some validations and business rules during the import of the data. Because you might define Aggregates that ensure the integrity of the system, well here I am speculating. But this is a scenario how I would applied DDD and to make the point that we cannot apply DDD to import. But import is potentially an implementation detail.